# Error cuando parseo dates con Arrow

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parsear

Al utilizar:

```
arrow.get("feb2015", locale="es", format="MMMYYYY")
```

estoy obteniendo

```
<Arrow [2015-01-01T00:00:00+00:00]>
```

cuando debería de obtener

```
<Arrow [2015-02-01T00:00:00+00:00]>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal??

Answer (score 0):

Realmente los únicos argumentos tipo keyword que acepta (más bien, que tiene en cuenta) `arrow.get` son `locale` y `tzinfo`. Al pasar el formato como keyword simplemente es ignorado.

Pasa el formato como argumento posicional después de la cadena que representa la fecha:

> ```
> >>> import arrow
> >>> arrow.get("feb2015", "MMMYYYY", locale="es")
> <Arrow [2015-02-01T00:00:00+00:00]>
> ```